# LINQ: Combining vectors

Tags: linq

I have two vectors of type float (to simplify here, I have used vector's length of 3 items):

```
float[] a = new float[] { 10.0f, 20.0f, 30.0f };
float[] b = new float[] { 5.0f, 10.0f, 20.0f };
```

I need to substract b from a in a pair wise way and keep two vectors (Result and remaining quantity). The result corresponds to a-b and the remaining quantity corresponds to that quantity that cannot be substracted from a (see example 2):

Example 1:

```
  a   |  b  | Result | Remaining quantity (quantity that cannot be substracted from a)
                                          (b remainder)
------------------------------------------------
10.0f   5.0f   5.0f      0f
20.0f  10.0f  10.0f      0f
30.0f  20.0f  10.0f      0f
```

In above example, remaining quantities are always 0 because b's quantities are always less or equal to a's quantities, but, if any quantity in b is greater than that in a, only the quantity of a can be substracted at most and then the remaining quantity should be b remainder that has not been possible to substract from a, for example, imagine following scenario:

Example 2:

```
float[] a = new float[] { 10.0f, 5.0f, 30.0f };
float[] b = new float[] { 5.0f, 10.0f, 20.0f };

  a   |  b  | Result | Remaining (quantity that cannot be substracted from a)
                                 (b remainder)
--------------------------------
10.0f   5.0f   5.0f     0f
 5.0f  10.0f   0.0f     5f
30.0f  20.0f  10.0f     0f
```

After operation I need to obtain in two vectors the Result and Remaining. How could it be done efficiently using LINQ and some function like Zip or something?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
I am trying to do the following:

```
                float[] remainder  = new float[<same lenght of a or b>];
                Result= a
                    .Zip(b, (x, y) =>
                        {
                            remainder[i] = 0;
                            if (y > x)
                            {
                                remainder[i] = y - x;
                                return 0;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                return x- y;
                            }
                        }).ToArray();
```

My problem now is to know how to get the index of the current iteration, in my case this 'i' is used but how to achieve this?

Comment: Yes, `Zip` is the way to go.

Comment: Do you know how get the index of the current iteration within zip?

Comment: You could Zip, followed by [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx) over load of Select.

Comment: @GertArnold: See my edit posted, how to know the current index of the current iteration, in my case it is marked as 'i'. How to use select as you have said?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you could do it.

```
Result = a.Zip(b, (x, y) => new { x, y }).Select((a,i) =>
                    {
                        remainder[i] = 0;
                        if (a.y > a.x)
                        {
                            remainder[i] = a.y - a.x;
                            return 0;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return a.x- a.y;
                        }
                    }).ToArray();
```

It uses the indexed overload of [IEnumerable.Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx).